# Debunk closed Boyle flask for perpetual energy

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, pressure

Somebody is insisting on this design to me, and while I cant put my finger on what exactly makes this impossible, I know it is. I need your help.

I believe it's to do with the pressure of the headspace, and losses in friction and heat causing motion to cease. But how can it cease when the pressure of the water at its deepest is so much higher than the headspace? It just messes me up.

[image]

This is a closed (yes, closed, no air/vapor in/out) system, with a shaft connected to the turbine inside sticking out of it. Of course, it exchanges heat with the ambient, so keeping that in mind, what will make this stop, or will it work at all?

Comment: The water on both sides is just going to find a height they both like and sit there.

Comment: get a cup of water and a drinking straw ... insert straw into the water until it almost touches the bottom of the cup ... does the water rise in the straw and flow out of the top end of the straw?

Comment: The fan / rotor means that it's not perpetual. See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/114929/170832 https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion#Capillary_bowl_.28Boyle.27s_Self-flowing_Fluid.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The steady-state of the system.*

> But how can it [the motion] cease when the pressure of the water at its deepest is so much higher than the headspace?

You're forgetting that the pressure in the pipe will be the same as the pressure in the tank.

**Pressure = force per unit area**. It doesn't matter what the relative cross-sections of the tank and pipe are - the pressures at any height will be the same in both.

If there was pressure exerted by the gas it would affect the tank and pipe the same amount and they will still self-level.

> ... will it work at all?

No.

Answer (score 1):

A siphon only works when the exit of the siphon is below the level of the supplying water.  This thing wouldn't do anything except sit there.  Figure out a way to make water run uphill and we'll really have something.